# How to have 2 TextViews on top of each other, with a Button on the right?

Tags: android

My understanding is that this should work if I use a vertical LinearLayout first, to get the two TextViews on top of each other, then nesting this vertical LinearLayout within a horizontal LinearLayout to accommodate the Button.

My code is as follows.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="306dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.079">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="225dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="154dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: any problem in this code ?

Comment: Nope, not as far as I know

Comment: It just doesn't give me the interface that I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `<Button>` to this:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="225dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="154dp" />
```

And vertical `LinearLayout` to this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Would you mind explaining the changes you made?

Comment: I see the biggest change is that you set android:layout weight="1", and button width to "match_parent". If button width is set to "match_parent", wouldn't it expand to cover up the entire screen instead?

Comment: @codinglearner21 yes "match_parent" means to expand and cover up the entire screen but when we put weights then space is divided proportionally like now we have given 1:3 ratio. Please upvote and accept the answer, if this has helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: I see, that's very helpful. Another small question, after I used your method, the whole thing works but it doesn't cover up the entire width of the screen. Is there something I can do about that? I suspect it has something to do with the first "main " LinearLayout being match_parent, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I can see some margin in your parent `CardView` this might be responsible, try removing them. Sorry not ConstraintLayout it is Cardview

Comment: Yes, turned out layout_width there needed to be set as "match_parent". Thanks for being such a great help!

Answer (score 0):

This can help you :-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```